# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in CodeIgniter's Tutorial

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have good command over core PHP, and I have just started learning CodeIgniter. I have created some pages according to the CodeIgniter's Tutorial. But I am stuck in this tutorial: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Following is the code:
**/application/config/routes.php :**

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['users/(:any)'] = 'users/view/$1';
$route['users'] = 'users';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

**/application/models/Users_model.php :**

```
class Users_model extends CI_Model
{   public function __construct()
    {   $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_users($username = FALSE)
    {   if ($username === FALSE)
        {   $query = $this->db->get('users');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username' => $username));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

**/application/controllers/Users.php :**

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{   public function __construct()
    {   parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('users_model');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }
    public function index()
    {   $data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_users();
        $data['title'] = 'List of Users';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('users/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function view($username = NULL)
    {   $data['user'] = $this->users_model->get_users($username);
        if (empty($data['user']))
        {   show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = $data['user']['display_name'];
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('users/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**/application/views/users/index.php :**

```
<div class='main'>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $user['display_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['email'] ?></td>
            <td>@<a href="<?php echo site_url('users/'.$user['username']) ?>"><?php echo $user['username'] ?></a></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

**/application/views/users/view.php :**

```
<h2><?php $user['display_name'] ?></h2>
<p>@<?php $user['username'] ?></p>
```

**MySQL 'users' table's structure :**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    username VARCHAR(255),
    display_name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

(You can replace `....` (4 dots) with your desired domain name OR localhost in the below code.)

Output of `..../index.php/users` page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List of Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>List of Users</h1>
<div class='main'>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nikunj Bhatt</td>
            <td>nikunj@example.com</td>
            <td>@<a href="..../index.php/users/NikunjBhatt">NikunjBhatt</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This output is proper, but when I click on the username, it is redirecting to `..../index.php/users/NikunjBhatt` page and this page is showing the error "This webpage is not available" "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in Google Chrome.

So, where is the problem? What I am missing?

Comment: Why this `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`?

Comment: try removing `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`

Comment: @devpro , up to how much I understood, it is to capture any other URLs which doesn't match with the defined routes. It is written in last section in the [tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html).

Comment: @PraveenKumar , I tried removing it too, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write code as below:-

```
public function view($username = ""){
 // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: why you need $route['users/(:any)'] = 'users/view/$1';
$route['users'] = 'users';

Comment: you can remove this $route['users/(:any)'] = 'users/view/$1';
$route['users'] = 'users'; and can use <a href="..../index.php/users/view/NikunjBhatt""

Comment: same error page which I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: did you given as i mentioned ?  <a href="..../index.php/users/view/NikunjBhatt""  ie  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/view/NikunjBhatt"><?php echo $user['username'] ?></a>